# Composite primary keys and foreign keys Code First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to create 2 entities, user and user reviews, where user reviews has a composite primary keys which are the ids of the users, the one who got reviewed and who did it, this composite primary key is also a foreign key to the primary key in the User's table, however EF is creating an extra column that I don't see the point in it, also when I save to the db an User Review object this column doesn't get populated , it's always empty.

This is causing that when I try retrieve an user with its reviews the reviews collection is always empty unless the **User_SubjectId** column contains the id of the user.

My query is like this

```
 return _context.Users
                .Include(u => u.Reviews)
                .Where(u => u.SubjectId.Equals(subjectId));
```

**The Reviews collection always is empty**

**User Review entity**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace API.Data.Entities
{
    public class UserReview
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("Reviewer")]
        public string ReviewerId { get; set; } //The user that wrote the review

        [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("ReviewedUser")]
        public string ReviewedUserId { get; set; } //The user who was reviewed

        [Required]
        [Range(1, 5)]
        public int Rating { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual User Reviewer { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual User ReviewedUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The User entity is like this

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public string SubjectId { get; set; }

        public User()
        {                
            Reviews = new List<UserReview>();
        }

        public virtual ICollection<UserReview> Reviews { get; set; }    
    }
```

However when I add the migration another columns gets created in my UserReviews table as shown on this picture, the column is **User_SubjectId**

[image]

I don't know if this is a bug in EF or I did my mapping wrong, in any case any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Your unknown column is created by the User.Reviews property. You have not map its foreign key, so EF will auto generate the name.

Comment: What do you mean is not mapped?, check my UserReview entity, the 2 foreign keys are there

Comment: Reviews is linked to which one of the foreign key?

Comment: Oh I see what are you saying, do you know how to specify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the ReverseProperty annotation.

```
public class UserReview
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("Reviewer")]
    public string ReviewerId { get; set; } //The user that wrote the review

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("ReviewedUser")]
    public string ReviewedUserId { get; set; } //The user who was reviewed

    [Required]
    [Range(1, 5)]
    public int Rating { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual User Reviewer { get; set; }

    [Required)]
    public virtual User ReviewedUser { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public string SubjectId { get; set; }

    public User()
    {                
        Reviews = new List<UserReview>();
    }

    [InverseProperty("ReviewedUser")] // or Reviewer.
    public virtual ICollection<UserReview> Reviews { get; set; }    
}
```

In my opinon, that's the kind of thing that are easier to configure when using fluent mapping.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using fluent mapping but your answer pointed me in the right direction.